# Facebook Connect Facepile error

Tags: facebook, xfbml

I've developed a simple website using facebook connect, and it has been working fine for the last month or so. Underneath the fb:login-button code is a fb:facepile. It has worked as expected until today, when instead of showing friend's pictures it displays the facebook homepage. Here is a screenshot of the problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZsbq.png

Here is the relevant code. It worked at one time, so I'm really confused what happened to cause this weird error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({appId: '<?php echo $appkey; ?>', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

            /* All the events registered */
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                // do something with response
                login();
            });

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
            // do something with response
                logout();
            });
        };

        (function() {
            var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.type = 'text/javascript';
            e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
              e.async = true;
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());

        function login(){
            document.location.href = "<?php echo $base_url.'/facebook/'; ?>";
        }

        function logout(){
            document.location.href = "<?php echo $base_url.'/logout/'; ?>";
        }
    </script>
```

I cannot copy the two XFBML tags that follow the javascript. They are fb:login-button and fb:facepile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a reported bug but it seems that nobody at Facebook care about it. Very strange and disapointing for such big web company.

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=90734

You can report this bug by upvoting at the follwoing webpage :

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=15490

Comment: I'm actually the one who wrote that first post on the facebook developer's forum. I wrote it the same time I submitted the question here on stackoverflow. Its a real shame they haven't even responded to the thread, although the bug tracker does have it marked as assigned which is somewhat promising.

Comment: Don't be fooled, it's not promising.  Facebook tech support blows.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `<fb:facepile></fb:facepile>` is finally working again. The [bug](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=15490) was marked as resolved on the Facebook bugtracker and is currently working as expected on my development server.